# Plus operator in JavaScript doesn't sum my values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate the number of payments but output was wrong so i tried to calculate a simple operation on the month value.But "+" operator doesn't sum my values it acts like string.For example 3 and 5,output isnt 8 its 35.

```
  <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mortgage Calculator</title>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var principal = princ.value;
            var interestrate = interest.value;
            var monthlypayment = monthly.value;
            var months=(principal)+(interestrate);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=months;

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Principal: <input type="text" id="princ" name="principal">
        <br>
        <br> Interest Rate: <input type="text" id="interest" name="interestrate">
        <br/>
        <br/> Monthly Payment: <input type="text" id="monthly"   name="monthlypayment">
    </form>
    <button onclick="validateForm()">Run</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your values are been treated as `String`s, so they are been concatenated together

Comment: Bad practice to call vars directly using the [DOM elements ID's](https://dev.to/buntine/dom-elements-with-ids-are-global-variables)

Comment: @kip quick question what should one do instead

Comment: @vikarjramun just declare your vars and use `querySelector` to get the DOM object's by the ID and set the values of this.. `var myVar = document.querySelector('#id').value`, avoid the collision of named variables and is more readable

Answer (score 1):

The actual type of the value is `string`. That's why string concatenation is happening. You have to use `parseInt` to convert string to integer to perform intended arithmetic operation.

**Change:**

`var months=(principal)+(interestrate);`

**To:**

`var months = parseInt(principal) + parseInt(interestrate);`

Comment: you ninja'd me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The values you are summing are strings. You need to convert them to integers:

```
parseInt(principal)+parseInt(interestate)
```

The reason for this is that input values are always strings. AFAIK, this is even if you set the type to `number`. `parseInt(s)` converts a string s to an int.

Answer (score -1):

```
var months=parseInt(principal)+parseInt(interestrate);
```

Values need to be converted to an integer first.

Comment: what does this answer contribute that is not there in the other two?

Comment: There were no other answers when I started posting this. I guess I'm getting down voted for being too slow to finish my answer...

Comment: Answer before mine is down voted as well. Someones having a bad day lol

Answer (score -1):

Your input values are treated as string as they are textbox inputs. Parse the values first before adding them up.

e.g.

`var principal = parseInt(princ.value);
 var interestrate = parseInt(interest.value);`